# Throw or not throw the exception from the methods consumed by the ASP.NET Web API layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception, asp.net-web-api

Assume that I am building an ASP.NET Web API application and it has the following structure:

[image]

As you can see from the diagram, the ASP.NET Web API core will talk to domain service layer (e.g. `MembershipService` class which has methods such as `GetUsers`, `CreateUser`, etc.) and my service classes will talk to one or multiple repositories to handle the operations.

It's very obvious that a service operation (such as `MembershipService.CreateUser` method) would fail for several reasons (unmet conditions, an exception thrown by the repository, etc.) and this is the place where I have the doubts.

Do you think that service classes should handle exceptions and return some sort of result object such as the below one:

```
public class OperationResult {

    public OperationResult(bool isSuccess) : this(isSuccess) {
        IsSuccess = isSuccess;
    }

    public OperationResult(bool isSuccess, Exception exception) : this(isSuccess) {
        Exception = exception;
    }

    public bool IsSuccess { get; private set; }
    public Exception IsSuccess { get; private set; }
}

public class OperationResult<TEntity> : OperationResult {

    public OperationResult(bool isSuccess) 
        : base(isSuccess) { }

    public OperationResult(bool isSuccess, Exception exception) 
        : base(isSuccess, exception) { }

    public TEntity Entity { get; set; }
}
```

Or do you think that the service methods shouldn't abstract the exception like that and should throw the exception directly or indirectly (creating a new meaningful exception type specific to operation and put the thrown exception as its inner exception)?

Comment: Who wanted to close this question as not constructive? Please tell me what you use to get high cuz it's working as far as I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are in-process, use exceptions.

Comment: Thanks! would you rather make the thrown exception flow or wrap it inside more meaningful custom exception type?

Comment: @tugberk  That's a big question.  Following the rules of layered architecture, you should wrap.  Is that the right thing to do all of the time?  I don't know.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the help. For example, I prefer already available .NET exceptions if that gives the necessary meaning (e.g. `ArgumentNullException`).

Answer (score 2):

I don't see ANY point in avoiding exceptions. Exceptions are there for good reasons, mainly to be used!
Just try to look at the big picture: you are trying to change Exception mechanism with the old fashion way of error checking. This way you'll lose all the merits of Exceptions (like separation of the error-handling and regular code, CallStack, ...) and gain nothing in return.

What I usually do in this situation is to catch the exception in service layer and rewrap it into a custom exception (with the reference to the original exception in the InnerException field).

Answer (score 1):

Taking a page from Microsoft's book, the implementation of the Membership API throws exceptions rather than handling them and returning a result object, so I would consider this a best practice as long as you don't control both the client and the API.

In the case where you do control both the client and the API, it is my personal preference to return a result object or an error message. The reason for this is that I want to log capture detailed information about the source of actual exceptions, but I don't want an exception for everything that could go wrong, such as the password being incorrect.

In this case, a simple error message to the user will be more than sufficient. From real-world experience, recording exceptions to the event log or log file every time a validation error occurs is a major burden on operations personnel that are trying to determine whether or not there is an actual fault occurring or whether it is just a user's typo.